# Implement a security model in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have got a SSRS report with the following hierarchy

Page A (root) -- Page B (child1) -- Page C (childe 1.1)

Meanwhile, there are 3 users having the following access

User A: page A

User B: page A B

User C: page A B C

How to implement this access control model in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

Security in SSRS depends on Roles and Tasks associated to users or groups.
A role is basically a container of tasks, and each Task gives a specific permissions in the SSRS server (read report, create report, etc...).

To achieve what you want, you need to associate users A, B and C to a Role (at least) with suficient rights to access Page A, Page B and Page C.

By default, the security is inherited in SSRS, so what you defined in Page A (root) will be true for Pages B and C.
BUT, in your case, you want to set explicitly the security, and so break this inheritance. For this, go to the menu "Manage folder" in the Welcome screen of your report server (http://serverAddress/Reports), and it will show the Security menu.
In this screen, add your 'User A' and set a Role to it (maybe 'Browser' role can be useful for test).
Go back to the welcome page, and repeat the operation by selected properties of "Page B" and then "Page C", and affect role to User B and C.

Hope this will help you.
Do not hesitate to ask me if you have more questions

Regards,

Comment: thanks but is there a way to use reference tables, which would be easier to do any change management?

Comment: Unfortunately, administration management in SSRS is quite dificult. There no way to manage natively and easily the security.
I am currently working on that point with my company, to have the easiet and fastest way possible to administer and manage security on SSRS server.

A other way you can try, is to manage roles by using SQL requests (as it is describe https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84406/view-the-role-assigned-to-each-user-report-server)